# "Remember of Majesty" - is this title correct?

Tags: meaning, grammar

There is a game, called "Remember of Majesty", but using a verb without any pronoun looks unfamiliar to me. Is this a correct construction? What's the meaning of the title? Is it like "you do remember of majesty!"? Or "Mind the majesty!"?

Comment: The phrase is not idiomatic English; the title seems to have been invented by a non-native speaker. _Remember_ doesn't need a preposition.

Comment: Exactly, it's created by a [Korean company](https://www.kakaogamescorp.com/).

Comment: I cannot paste [the original Korean name](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EB%A1%AC:_%EB%A6%AC%EB%A9%A4%EB%B2%84_%EC%98%A4%EB%B8%8C_%EB%A7%88%EC%A0%9C%EC%8A%A4%ED%8B%B0) but it seems to be pronounced *lom: limembeo obeu majeseuti*, i.e. a form of transliteration into Korean of "ROM: Remember of Majesty".  Something like *Kingdom's Memory* might be more idiomatic but could have been too close to other game names.

Comment: "Think of majesty" would be fine, but "remember" doesn't work like that.

Comment: Google Translate also does it literally Rom: Remember of Majesty [The less trustworthy ChatGPT does exactly the same] It is little more than word salad in English. You could try to make sense of it, but I wouldn't bother. [oddly, the comments here will not allow me to post the Korean, even in code block, idk why.]

Comment: M-W has the sense 'remind' for the transitive verb, but marked as an archaic usage. 'Remind of glory days' would in any case be incomplete without a direct object. // Not as random as a word salad, as 'Echoes / Memorials of Glory Days' is obviously intended, but an incorrect attempt to express this.

Comment: Titles don't have to be grammatical.